# javascript not working if input type is not present

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table which contain input types such as checkbox, text as below

```
var inputBoxes = table_check.getElementsByTagName('input'); //modified to get only input tags present within the table 

 for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
Nos1=parseInt(inputBoxes[i+1].value);item_row_no=1;
if(inputBoxes[i].value){alert('No Input Box');} //fails at this if clause
else{Nos2=0;}
```

If there is less than 5 Input Types present inside the table it should throw alert.

**Excepted result :** `No Input Box` from alert

**Actual result :** `<nothing thrown>` if input type is less than 5;

The above script is working fine if there is exactly 5 input types inside the table.

Comment: Why don't you check the length of inputboxes??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `i<inputBoxes.length` as your for condition.

```
for(var i=0; i<inputBoxes.length; i++) {
   Nos1=parseInt(inputBoxes[i+1].value);
   item_row_no=1;
   if(inputBoxes[i].value){
      alert('No Input Box');
   } else {
      Nos2=0;
   }
}
```

If for whatever reason you want to keep the `i<5` condition you would need to check the existence of the array element and not the `.value`, you should have been getting errors on the console because of the way your if was setup. Use the below:

```
if(!inputBoxes[i]){
   console.log("Input Box "+ i +" Does Not Exist");
} else {
   Nos2=0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. If you just want to add a condition based on the number of input types, you can just use like given below.

```
var inputBoxes = table_check.getElementsByTagName('input'); //modified to get only input tags present within the table 
if(inputBoxes.length<5){
  alert('No Input Box');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`inputBoxes` is an HTMLCollection.

Turn it into an `array` like so:

```
var inputBoxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
inputBoxes = Array.prototype.slice.call(inputBoxes);
```

Then you can check if the inputBox is defined like so

```
if(inputBoxes[i] == undefined){
  alert('No Input Box');
}
```